# SQL или NoSQL для задачи?

Tags: sql, база-данных, mongodb, проектирование, nosql

Не могу разобраться в структуре хранения данных в РБД для своей задачки.
Задача создать поиск данных по параметрам(фильтрам/тэгам). Параметры эти не фиксированы, может быть любое множество.
Хочу создать эффективную для поиска структуру бд.

Пример:

```
id| Item      | tags
1 | bmw X6    | {#car, #russia, #black, #bmw, ...}
2 | bmw X5    | {#car, #russia, #black, #bmw, ...}
3 | Spaghetti | {#food, #spain, #pasta}
```

Т.е каждому "Item" будет принадлежать от 1 до n тэгов.
Тэги эти могут создавать пользователи.

Использовал только РБД, но слышал, что NoSQL возможно для использования более гибких данных или это не так ?

Подскажите стоит ли посмотреть в сторону noSQL(MongoDB например) или создать структуру для обычной Реляционной БД ?

Answer (score 2):

NoSQL эффективен там где много данных и причем данные плохо или совсем неструктурированы - типичный пример: собственно сам Интернет по сути есть свалка неструктурированных данных.

В вашем случае реляционная БД вполне подойдет. Те же теги типичный пример реализации отношения *один-ко-многим* (один `item` много `tags`)